# IP address of form submitter (remote IP address) using Perl and HTML::Mason

Tags: html, perl, mason

I am using [`HTML::Mason`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aMason) to serve a web page containing a form. When the form is filled and submitted, I want to know the IP address of the remote client.

I tried printing `$r->headers_in` but I get

```
Apache2::Request=SCALAR(0x1961ba0)->headers_in
```

am I using the wrong argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CGI application, the remote IP address is in `$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}`.

If you are using mod_perl, then the equivalent value is at `$r->connection->remote_ip` where `$r` is your `Apache2::Request` object.

The output you show will be produced if you have the method call in double quotes, like

```
print "$r->headers_in\n"
```

it will work properly if you remove the quotes

```
print $r->headers_in, "\n"
```

The `$r->headers_in` method returns an [`APR::Table`](https://metacpan.org/module/APR%3a%3aTable) object. You can dump the contents of this using the `do` method and a suitable subroutine (which must return `1` for the iteration through the table to continue) like this:

```
my $table = $r->headers_in;
$table->do(sub {
  printf "%s: %s\n", @_;
  1;
});
```

Comment: thanks,this is a basic question. how would i print the content of APR::Table=HASH(0x59d0b30) which is what print $r->headers_in is giving me. i want to see the different parts of $r->headers_in ? a newbie

Comment: @mamesaye: I've added to my answer to describe how to print the return value of `headers_in`.

Comment: thkx,saved me some hours, you know u'r stuff